# How can I conditionally import a node module?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules, metro-bundler

I have a react native project that uses the following platforms: Web, IOS, Android, Windows, MacOs.

I have two packages that do not allow Android to build if my React Native version is below 0.70.0. I can not upgrade my RN version.

Specifically these packages are: react-native-worklets-core and react-native-vision-camera.

To continue development I copy a fake version of the above modules into my node_modules folder but this is obviously a poor approach and is not something I can keep in my project.

Here is the code in my package.json file for your reference to help understand my problem:

```
"replace-vision-camera": "rm -rf ./node_modules/react-native-vision-camera && cp -R ./fake_modules/react-native-vision-camera ./node_modules/react-native-vision-camera",
"replace-worklets-core": "rm -rf ./node_modules/react-native-worklets-core && cp -R ./fake_modules/react-native-worklets-core ./node_modules/react-native-worklets-core"
```

So my question is, how can I build android without these packages? Would it be something in my metro config file?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add a react-native.config.js at the top level of your RN project, and you can disable autolinking for dependency foo on android with contents:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    "foo": {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
      }
    }
  }
}
```